# How to select different tuples from the same table?

Tags: sql, database, oracle

How to select different tuples from the same table?  I want to find pairs of sid's of students who are enrolled in 2 or more classes together.

Table schema: enroll(sid*, dname*, cno*, sectno*, grade)

Answer (score 2):

You could perform a self-join. Note that you have to add a condition on the `sid`s so you don't double the pairs (e.g., get `[1, 3]` and `[3, 1]`). Here, I decided that the left side should always be the lower number, but you could go the other way too:

```
SELECT   a.sid, b.sid
FROM     enroll a
JOIN     enroll b ON a.cno = b.cno AND a.sid < b.sid
GROUP BY a.sid, b.sid
HAVING   COUNT(*) >= 2
```